# Measurable set with respect to a product measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be two measure spaces. Suppose that $A\times B\subset X\times Y$ is measurable with respect to the product measure $\mu\times\nu$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Is $A\in\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Is your product measure defined on the $\sigma$ algebra generated by the measurable rectangles $A\times B$ with $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$ or on its completion? In the latter case thing about the product of two Lebesgue measures on$\Bbb R$ and the product of the Vitali set with a singleton

Comment: hi, it is defined on the $\sigma$ algebra generated by the measurable rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal A =\mathcal B=$ Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$, $\mu=\nu=$ Lebesgue measure and $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb R$ which is not a Borel set then  $A\times \mathbb R$ is measurable with respect to the product measure but $A \notin \mathcal A$. If you really meant that $A\times B$ is $\mathcal A \times\mathcal B$ then it does follow that $A \in \mathcal A$. This is part of Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: I think your counter-example works. I didn't mean $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$.  Thanks a lot for your help!